# Masking a date value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help me to mask a date.
I have two condition:

- In first one Only the year value will be masked.
       Eg.:06/25/XXXX
- And in the second condition only Month and Date will be masked.
       Eg.:XX/XX/2016

I didn't got anything relevant to it in the web.
Can someone please help me to sort this out.
It will be better if a fiddler example is provided.

Comment: Show your code please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do this work. Using `replace()` method, change target character to another.

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var date = $("#date1").text();
    date = date.replace(/[\d]+$/, "xxxx");
    $("#date1").text(date); 
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
    var date = $("#date2").text();
    date = date.replace(/[\d]+\/[\d]+/, "xx/xx");
    $("#date2").text(date); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Change</button>
<span id="date1">05/26/2016</span>
<br/><br/>
<button id="button2">Change</button>
<span id="date2">05/26/2016</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you want something like this :

**Fiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/cL9mw5e4/

**Code**

```
function maskAndAlertDate(format){
var currDate = new Date();
switch(format){
case "mask-year":
    alert(currDate.getUTCDate()+"/"+parseInt(currDate.getUTCMonth()+1)+"/xxxx");
  break;
case "mask-date":
   alert("xx/xx/"+currDate.getUTCFullYear());
   break;
}

}

maskAndAlertDate("mask-year");
maskAndAlertDate("mask-date");
```

Comment: Thank's for the quick response, this is what I was looking for but still I have one confusion.. You are masking a current date what if I want to mask a old date like" 5/5/1990 " .